# Modernizer is undefined when resolved by requirejs

Tags: requirejs

I'm using RequireJS 2.1.6.

Here's the main.js file:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        baseUrl: "/Scripts",
        products: "Products/products",
        jquery: "jquery-2.0.2.min",
        modernizr: "modernizr-2.6.2"
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: "$"
        },
        modernizr: {
            exports: "modernizr"
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the Products.js file declaration:

```
define(["modernizr"], function (modernizr) {
    // Rest of code.
});
```

The problem is that `modernizr` is `undefined` when I execute the code in `Products.js`. If I remove the parameter `modernizr` and instead use the `Modernizr` variable instead (which is naturally exposed by Modernizer.js globally), then the code works fine. However, this is not my ideal setup.

I've double-checked the spelling, and the config, but I cannot understand why this is the case. I assume I've missed a fundamental point here, so I'm hoping someone can explain where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        baseUrl: "/Scripts",
        products: "Products/products",
        jquery: "jquery-2.0.2.min",
        modernizr: "modernizr-2.6.2"
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: "$"
        },
        modernizr: {
            exports: "Modernizr"
        }
    }
});
```

Modernizr exposes `Modernizr` and not `modernizr`.

Comment: DOH! Of course. Good grief, I should have realised that I need to export what the library already exports globally. Cheers.